# How to add properties to Javascript array recursively with a one liner?

Tags: javascript

I want to add a specific property to a Javascript object that is not allocated yet and is part of a parent object. Usually I do the following:

```
let obj = {};

if(!obj["property"])
{
    obj["property"] = {};
}

obj["property"]["property2"] = value;
```

Can the code above be written with a one liner and without the object allocation inside the if statement?

To compare with Linux, I would like to have something similar to mkdir -p ./a/b instead of mkdir a; cd a; mkdir b.

Thank you.

Comment: There has been talk of JS having a null-coalescing operator, but not sure where that stands right now.

Comment: @ziggywiggy See [nullish coalescing](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-nullish-coalescing) and [optional chaining](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining). This will work fine for getting a property path, but they don't support any syntax for setting. What you'd need is something like `(obj["property"] ?= {})["property2"] = value`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can do it like this:

```js
let obj = {};


(obj["property"] = obj["property"] || {})["property2"] = "value";


console.log(obj);
```

It takes advantage of the `||` operator to check for a falsey value, so this will only work reliably when you're checking for an object or some value that's always truthy.

It then takes advantage of the fact that the `=` operator returns the value being assigned. Since it's an object, and objects in JS are a reference type, you can assign a property to it, and it will mutate the object that was previously assigned.

However, this is ugly. I don't think there should be so much emphasis placed on writing "one liner" code.

Answer (score 1):

ziggy wiggy solution will work.

Alternatively though you could also do `obj = {...obj, property: {...obj.property, property2: value}};`

this is actually slower because it creates a new object and then assigns it to obj but is preferable *if* you want to leave `obj` untouched, and in that case just assign the result to a new variable. (`const obj2 ={...obj, property: {...obj.property, property2: value}};`)

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce the given keys and assign at the last step the value.

This works for an arbitrary count of keys.

```
["property", "property2"]
    .reduce((o, k, i, { length }) => o[k] = o[k] || (i + 1 === length ? value : {}), obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are great, but as an alternative, you can use lodash's [`set`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#set):

```js
const { set } = _; // import { set } from "lodash";

let obj = {};
set(obj, "property.property2", "value");

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```